# display multiple items with different statuses

Tags: php

I don’t know how to search the net for the answer and I’m not sure how to explain the problem, so I’m sorry if it’s not clear or if it’s been asked before.

Here’s the deal: I need to show some items which have different statuses (there’s “unanswered”, “in discussion” and “answered”). What’s happening now is that the unanswered questions are being shown, the correct text is being shown for the questions that are in discussion, but the text for the question that are answered is the same as the “in discussion”. When one of the questions is moved from “unanswered” to “in discussion”, the correct text is being show for the “answered” questions. When there are no “unanswered” questions, the text is correct for that item. But the other items are getting the same text as the “unanswered” and the questions that should be shown in “in discussion” aren’t visible.

Does someone know what I can do to fix this? I'll put some code below. Thanks!!!

overzicht.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['views']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else
{
    $feedback = "";
    try
    {
        include_once('classes/question.class.php');
        $oQuestion = new Question();
        $oQuestionsUnanswered = $oQuestion->getQuestionsUnanswered();
        $oQuestionsInDiscussion = $oQuestion->getQuestionsInDiscussion();
        $oQuestionsAnswered = $oQuestion->getQuestionsAnswered();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

To show the different items (this is repeated twice for the other 2 statuses, with other variables e.g $oQuestionsAnswered):

```
<h3>Vragen onbeantwoord:</h3>
        <div id="questionUnanswered">
        <?php
            if(isset($oQuestionsUnanswered))
            {
                $unanswered_details = "";
                while($arr_unanswered = mysqli_fetch_array($oQuestionsUnanswered))
                {
                    $unanswered_details .= "<div class='head'>";
                    $unanswered_details .= "<div class='titel'>";
                    $unanswered_details .= "<a href='full_topic.php?id=".$arr_unanswered['bericht_id']."'>".$arr_unanswered['bericht_titel']."</a></div>";
                    $unanswered_details .= "<div class='datum'>" . $arr_unanswered['bericht_datum'] . "</div></div>";
                }
                echo $unanswered_details;
                }
            else
            {
                echo $feedback;
            }
        ?>
        </div>
```

question.class.php (this is also repeated for the other 2)

```
public function getQuestionsUnanswered()
    {
        include('connection.class.php');
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM tblbericht
                WHERE fk_status_id = 3;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows!=0)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Er zijn momenteel nog geen onbeantwoorde vragen");
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you make a big mistake, you split the query moment from the fetch moment, so you can create an array of question objects, than you use it inside the page.

Here's a **draft** of your code adapted:

```
public function getQuestionsUnanswered()
    {
        include('connection.class.php');
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM tblbericht
                WHERE fk_status_id = 3;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $_rv =array()
        if($result->num_rows!=0)
        {
                while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $_rv[] = new QuestionBean($arr);                    
                }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Er zijn momenteel nog geen onbeantwoorde vragen");
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return $_rv
    }
```

Then

```
<h3>Vragen onbeantwoord:</h3>
        <div id="questionUnanswered">
        <?php
            if(count($oQuestionsUnanswered))
            {
                $unanswered_details = "";
                foreach( $oQuestionsUnanswered as $bean)
                {
                    $unanswered_details .= "<div class='head'>";
                    $unanswered_details .= "<div class='titel'>";
                    $unanswered_details .= "<a href='full_topic.php?id=".$bean->bericht_id."'>".$bean->bericht_titel."</a></div>";
                    $unanswered_details .= "<div class='datum'>" . $bean->bericht_datum . "</div></div>";
                }
                echo $unanswered_details;
                }
            else
            {
                echo $feedback;
            }
        ?>


</div>
```

Of course you can optimize it using 1 class for all kind of question and 1 function using the paramiter to select wich kind of question you need.

The type of question will be a parameter of QuestionBean.

QuestionBean is a Bean :)

As bean I mean a "simple" data object where each attributes has a getter and setter OR is public.

I use the __constructor as initializer with a function called populate:

```
class simpleBean{
  public $id;
  public function __construct($params){
    // some logic as need
  }

  // simple populate
  public function populate($params){
    $valid =  get_class_vars ( self );
    foreach($params as $k => $v){
      if(!isset($valid[$k]){
        // if this key has no attrib matchig I skip it
        continue;
      }
      $this->$k = $v;
    }
  }
}

class QuestionBean extend simpleBean{
  public $attr1;
  public function __construct($params){
    // may be I've some common logic in parent
    parent::__construc($params);

    // 
    $this->populate($params);
  } 
}
```

Now after the

```
            while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $_rv[] = new QuestionBean($arr);                    
            }
```

you will have an array ($rv) of beans, each bean is a single result row of your query, but it's an object, that's much better than a stupid array.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been realy busy. Could you plz explain it a bit more. I've searched the internet for QuestionBean, but didn't realy get any wiser. I've added the classes QuestionBean and OracleBean from assembla.com/code/..., and included QuestionBean.php in the function but I'm getting a notice: "Notice: Undefined property: QuestionBean::$bericht_id on line 82 (= the href line the foreach).